# FancyBox, Obtaining an ATTR of the item clicked

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-plugins, css-selectors, fancybox

I have the following lines of code:

```
    $("a.quickview").fancybox({
        ajax : {
            type    : "POST",
            data    : 'itemID=' + $(this).attr("name")
        }
    });
```

Which is binding on:

```
<a name="614" class="quickview" href="/URL/index.cfm">quick view</a>
```

I want data to post as itemID=614, but $(this).attr("name") is coming back as undefined? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are using [Fancybox 2.0](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/), you can do this:

```
$("a.quickview").fancybox({
    ajax : {
        type    : "POST",
        data    : 'itemID=' + $(this.element).attr("name")
    }
});]
```

Source: [Code snippet from fancyBox Github issue](https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues/59#issuecomment-3138366) (this works) =>

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
  beforeShow : function() {
    this.title = $(this.element).attr('fancybox-title');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

The way you wrote it `$(this)` is not what you expect. `this` in this context isn't the `a` clicked on but whatever `this` is when you run `$("a.quickview").fancybox({...})`.

Use this code instead

```
$("a.quickview").each(function() {
    var a = $(this);
    a.fancybox({
        ajax : {
            type    : "POST",
            data    : 'itemID=' + a.attr("name");
        }
    });
});
```

or if there is only one `a.quickview` you want to bind fancybox to use this simpler code

```
var a = $("a.quickview");
a.fancybox({
    ajax : {
        type    : "POST",
        data    : 'itemID=' + a.attr("name");
    }
});
```

Comment: there is a list of quickview's <ul>.... I just tried the code it no matter which quickview I click, it always is finding the name ATTR for the first A in the list <LI>, and not the one I clicked on... Ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by list of quickview's `<ul>`? Your selector says `a.quickview` which means all `<a>` tag that have the class quickview

Answer (score 2):

This did it for me:

> onComplete: function( instance, slide ) {
>
> ```
> // Clicked element
> console.info( slide.opts.$orig );
> ```
>
> }

Comment: This answer gave me the hint I needed. Fancybox 3: this.opts.$orig